# Android ReselectedListener for NavigationView

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigation, android-navigationview, android-bottomnavigationview

In [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/package-summary) it is possible to set:

```
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(item -> {
        // do nothing on reselection
    });
```

However for [NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/navigation/package-summary) this is not available. What is a good equivalent?

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to **@ande** I implemented the following:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (currentMenuItemId == item.getItemId()) {
        navDrawer.close();
        return true;
    }
    currentMenuItemId = item.getItemId();
    NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController);
    navDrawer.close();
    return true;
}
```

That works well for if I only navigate via the menu items. (Btw, I just implemented the Listener in my Activity and added it from there, no need for an extra class)
However, when I press the back button then I will be able to press the menu button for the current destination, as the menu item did not update on `onBackPressed()`.

---

**Update 2**

```
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
            currentMenuItemId = destination.getId();
        }
    });
```

This solved it!

Comment: Why you are saying `NavigationView` doesn't have [setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/navigation/NavigationView#setnavigationitemselectedlistener)?; correct me if I didn't get something

Comment: @Zain Your link points to `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` and not **RE** selected. Follow my two links and you see the missing interface

Comment: @Zain do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Are you using a NavController?

Comment: @TahaMalik yes I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can do like this ( I did quickly so may be it could be better!!)

```
    class ReSelectedListener(val navigationViewCallBack: NavigationViewCallBack) : NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    var newItemSelected : MenuItem? = null
    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if(newItemSelected != null){
            if(newItemSelected!!.itemId == item.itemId){
                navigationViewCallBack.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(item)
            }
        }
        newItemSelected = item
        return true
    }


}

interface NavigationViewCallBack {
    fun setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(item: MenuItem)
}
```

And after

```
class YourFragment :Fragment(), NavigationViewCallBack
```

and

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(ReSelectedListener(this))
```

and implements callback method in YourFragment:

```
 override fun setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(item: MenuItem) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! That brought me one step further. When clicking a menu item twice this works well. However after pressing the back button, this does not prevent current view to be reloaded as the `newItemSelected` was not updated in onBackPressed. Please see my update above!

Comment: @Tobi, if you have your navController, then you can add a addOnDestinationChangedListener on it and after you have a destination id and you can do when(destination.id) { id.toto -> currentItem = yourIdMenu }

Comment: how do I get the `MenuItem` object based on the destination.id ? Is item.id the same as destination.id ?

Comment: I solved it! Thanks! item.id = destination.id :)
 When you update the answer I will accept it

Comment: @Tobi, great, yes it was this but be carefull, because may be destination.id is not a menuItem.id !

Comment: true I have destinations that are no menuItems. But this is ok, because then it will be possible to click every menuItems! And once a menuItem was clicked, it will be blocked again :)